# Pivot table, find common attribute between exactly two rows

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have the following pivot table `chat_user` connecting User objects to Chat objects. 
[image: table image]

The behavior is that any number of Chats might exist, with 2 or more participants. I have illustrated this case here. I am trying to formulate an efficient query that will take as input user_id 16 and user_id 29391 and, in case such a chat_id exists where exactly these two user_ids participate (chat_id 1 in this example), return it for further processing. It should ignore matches where other users participate as well, such as chat_id 2.

Because of the way the system was designed, this table may reach N^2 where N is number of Users, without considering group chats. I need a query that can crunch through such numbers (possibly millions of rows) in reasonable syncron response time, which as I'm writing this out sounds less and less possible.

So I'm looking for a MySQL wizard to tell me whether this is reasonable or even possible or if I should seriously redesign this arrangement. I made it this way to support 1to1 chats as well as group chats, whilst maintaining full referential integrity. I'm also trying to re-use as much code as possible as this chat is only a small component of a large web application. I was *really* trying to avoid having to do 1to1 and group chats as different models with separate storage and all, but if this is insane then I have no choice. I've had great results with sql wizardry before so I remain optimistic.

Also please do go into at least moderate detail, I am pretty novice when it comes to SQL so I might not be able to piece basic instructions together.

***TL;DR*** : Query that takes two user_id as input and returns a chat_id if and only if exactly 2 rows match the given user_ids with some chat_id in common. Is this too hard for a possibly millionaire row table?

Edit:: Here is what I have working at the moment

```
SELECT u1.chat_id
FROM   chat_user u1 
       INNER JOIN chat_user u2 
               ON u1.chat_id = u2.chat_id 
WHERE  (u1.user_id = ? AND u2.user_id = ? ) 
       AND u1.chat_id IN (SELECT chat_id 
                          FROM   chat_user 
                          GROUP  BY chat_id 
                          HAVING Count(chat_id) = 2)
```

Edit2:: copy-paste table to get anyone interested in trying started quickly

```
CREATE TABLE `chat_user` (
  `chat_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `engaged` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `chat_user` (`chat_id`, `user_id`, `engaged`) VALUES
(1, 16, 1),
(1, 29391, 1),
(2, 16, 1),
(2, 555, 0),
(2, 29391, 1),
(3, 14, 0),
(3, 29391, 1);

ALTER TABLE `chat_user` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`chat_id`,`user_id`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach it:

```
SELECT u1.chat_id
FROM chat_user AS u1
JOIN chat_user AS u2 
  ON u1.chat_id = u2.chat_id
LEFT JOIN chat_user AS u3 
  ON u3.chat_id = u1.chat_id AND u3.user_id NOT IN (u1.user_id, u2.user_id)
WHERE u1.user_id = ? AND u2.user_id = ? 
 AND u3.chat_id IS NULL;
```

You'll need indexes on `(user_id, chat_id)` and on `(chat_id, user_id)`. The primary key you defined is sufficient for the latter index.

Comment: I ended up going with this solution, sorry for being 2 years late haha